# wordpress .htaccess redirectmatch or rewriterule date /2014/08/19 to ?year=2014 etc

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to rewrite a folder date format to a querystring,

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/my-calendar/([0-9999]+)/([0-99]+)/([0-99]+) /my-calendar/?year=$1
```

This does display the year correctly but I how do I get the second month folder into the querystring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^my-calendar/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/[0-9]+ /my-calendar/?year=$1&month=$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Your pattern `[0-9999]+` essentially means `[0-9]+`.

Make sure this rule is **very first rule** just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: how do I get the month? i I use $2 I just get my-calendar/?year=2014&month=

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.